# Python, pygame mouse position and which button is pressed

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to get my code collecting which mouse button is pressed and its position yet whenever I run the below code the pygame window freezes and the shell/code keeps outputting the starting position of the mouse. Does anybody know why this happens and more importantly how to fix it?
*(For the code below I used this website https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html and other stack overflow answers yet they were not specific enough for my problem.)*

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Set the height and width of the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([700,400])

pygame.display.set_caption("Operation Crustacean")


while True:
    clock.tick(1)
    screen.fill(background_colour)

    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex,mousey=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    print(click)
    print(mousex,mousey)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call one of the [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) functions regularly (for example `pygame.event.pump` or `for event in pygame.event.get():`), otherwise `pygame.mouse.get_pressed` (and some joystick functions) won't work correctly and the pygame window will become unresponsive after a while.

Here's a runnable example:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pygame.Color('gray12')

done = False
while not done:
    # This event loop empties the event queue each frame.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Quit by pressing the X button of the window.
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # MOUSEBUTTONDOWN events have a pos and a button attribute
            # which you can use as well. This will be printed once per
            # event / mouse click.
            print('In the event loop:', event.pos, event.button)

    # Instead of the event loop above you could also call pygame.event.pump
    # each frame to prevent the window from freezing. Comment it out to check it.
    # pygame.event.pump()

    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print(click, mousex, mousey)

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
```

Comment: I've added the example in which I show you how to use an event loop or `pygame.event.pump`. You could also use `pygame.event.wait` or `pygame.event.poll`.